# Wireguard with multiple local subnets using iptables

Tags: linux, iptables, vpn, linux-networking, wireguard

I'm trying to allow multiple local subnets when using a wireguard VPN. Below is the iptables config from my wireguard config file.

I'm assuming I have to write this in a different way, but I have no idea how to correct it.

```
PostUp = iptables -I OUTPUT ! -o %i -m mark ! --mark $(wg show %i fwmark) -m addrtype ! --dst-type LOCAL ! -d 172.16.0.0/24,10.0.0.0/24 -j REJECT
PostUp = ip6tables -I OUTPUT ! -o %i -m mark ! --mark $(wg show %i fwmark) -m addrtype ! --dst-type LOCAL -j REJECT
PreDown = iptables -D OUTPUT ! -o %i -m mark ! --mark $(wg show %i fwmark) -m addrtype ! --dst-type LOCAL ! -d 172.16.0.0/24,10.0.0.0/24 -j REJECT
PreDown = ip6tables -D OUTPUT ! -o %i -m mark ! --mark $(wg show %i fwmark) -m addrtype ! --dst-type LOCAL -j REJECT
```

It works just fine when I only have 1 subnet specified, but I get "iptables v1.8.9 (nf_tables): ! not allowed with multiple source or destination IP addresses" when I use 2 subnets.

Answer (score 0):

try in two entries.

> PostUp.... subnet1 REJECT
> PostUp.... subnet2 REJECT

Comment: I tried the putting each value on a single line and it did not work.  It seems to only take the second of the 2 entries.  It doesn't send an error, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: I just realized in the first message you say , i m trying to allow some subnet but in your entries you use reject and not accept ?